# About ember cli, can't type in command after ember serve

Tags: ember.js, terminal, osx-yosemite, ember-cli

I want to ask Im using ember cli, after the ember serve command, the prompt wasnt there and I cant type in command. What's the best way to keep using ember cli without exiting the whole terminal. (It doesn't matter the serve success o not, I can't type in either way). My system is Mac Yosimite.
Thanks

Comment: The answer do solve my problem, but just out of curiosity, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit command + t and a new tab will open. You can type more commands in that tab while ember serve is running.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you use Michael's solution, but you could also do `ctrl` + `Z` and then the command `bg`. You can bring ember to the foreground again by using `fg`.